# Symfony2 routing.yml setting routing_frontend.yml and routing_backend.yml in same directory

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6

im trying to learn symfony2, but the routing make me confuse

i have successfully generate both of the bundle and also controller with action

i wanna manage all my routing in same place other than putting each routing pattern in each *bundle/resource/config/routing.yml

so i set my **app/config/routing.yml** like this

**routing.yml**

```
backend:
    resource: routing_backend.yml
    prefix: /admin

frontend:
    resource: routing_frontend.yml
    prefix: /
```

then is ok when i surf localhost/ , but error at localhost/admin

```
No route found for "GET /admin"
```

but when i reorder the routing.yml config like this

**routing.yml**

```
frontend:
    resource: routing_frontend.yml
    prefix: /

backend:
    resource: routing_backend.yml
    prefix: /admin
```

then is ok when i surf localhost/admin but error at localhost/

```
No route found for "GET /"
```

**routing_frontend.yml**

```
index:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: vRonnPageBundle:Page:index }
```

**routing_backend.yml**

```
index:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: vRonnAdminPageBundle:Page:index }
```

Comment: Try the `/admin/` (with a slash at the end) URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i know it after i check all the available route with command **php app/console router:debug** and there is only one route name **index**, the route name must be unique or will replaced

**routing_frontend.yml**

```
frontend_index:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: vRonnPageBundle:Page:index }
```

**routing_backend.yml**

```
backend_index:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: vRonnAdminPageBundle:Page:index }
```